# Queue appending more then one entry

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, queue

I keep getting the first entry appended 4 times instead of one time.. when I append my first entry to the Queue it appends it 4 times..I thought this might be the problem..but it looks like it isn't. I can't find where the problem is..

I also created a print function for the nodes, and it showes that there are 4 of the same entries in the queue, so it is not a printing problem. And it doesn't look like it's in the read function. Maybe it's in the logic of the append function?? Still working on it..

This is the output: *3X^2 + 3X^2 + 3X^2 + 3X^2 + 1* but it should be *3X^2 + 1*

This is my append function:

```
//Append(Add) item to back of queue.
Error_code Extended_queue::append(const Queue_entry &item) {
    Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear = new Node<Queue_entry>(item);

    if(rear == nullptr){
        front = new_rear; // I also tried rear = new_rear; front = rear;            rear = new_rear;        
    }
    else {
        rear->next = new_rear;
        rear = new_rear;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And here is the code that prints the output:

```
This is the node code declaration:

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

enum Error_code{success,underflow,overflow}; // Used in node containing classes

template <class Node_entry> // Template to allow for more varience

// Part of a linked structure
struct __declspec(align(1)) Node{
    Node_entry entry; // Data contained in the node
    Node *next;   //Pointer to next node
    //constructors
    Node(); // Creates empty node
    Node(Node_entry item, Node *add_on = nullptr); // Creates node with specified data and pointer to next node
};

/* Post: The Node is initialized to contain nothing, and to have a null pointer.*/
template <class Node_entry>
Node<Node_entry>::Node()
{
    entry = nullptr;
    next = nullptr;
}

/* Post: The Node is initialized to contain item, and to point to add_on.*/
template <class Node_entry>
Node<Node_entry>::Node(Node_entry item, Node *add_on)
{
    entry = item;
    next = add_on;
}


#endif
```

Comment: Output of what? Are we to guess what you're doing and what your code is?

Comment: Um.. sorry, I edited it.

Comment: That warning should be disabled by default.  Are you using `/Wall`?  (While `/Wall` is useful on some compilers, it is in my opinion not useful on Visual C++.  The number of spurious warnings it issues is astounding.)

Comment: @James McNellis: Your comment and my response crossed each other :)

Comment: No problems. Like @James says, that's a pretty superfluous warning. (I can't believe it's a warning at all.) Also, like I mentioned on your other question, `new_rear` will never be null; remove the check.

Comment: To me the print code looks Okay. May be you need to look at the data structure pointed to by 'front' and see why redundant entries are there. Remove the warning message from your POST as it is misleading....

Comment: So, since you are using Visual C++, you do know that there is a spectacularly easy to use debugger included in Visual Studio, right?  If you add a breakpoint to the top of the function causing problems and look at your locals, you should easily be able to see what the problem is; if that fails, step through the function and see how the program state changes on each line.

Comment: It looks like once i hit Node<Queue_entry> *new_rear = new Node<Queue_entry>(item); in append, then i get "expression cannot be evaluated"..

Comment: When i get to the node constructor, the &item reference changes to -  item {degree=??? coefficient=??? } const Term &
instead of what it was before it got to the constructor.. -  item {degree=2 coefficient=3.0000000000000000 } const Term &  and i don't see a problem in the node constructor implementation.. :(

Comment: Is there any way I could improve my node constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the copy constructor had bad logic. After I fixed th constructor, the driver only returned the first term as front and rear entry. So I had to fix up the overloaded = operator as well.

New Code(for copy constructor):

```
Extended_queue::Extended_queue(const Extended_queue &original){
    Node<Queue_entry> *temp_node, *original_node = original.front;
    if(original.empty()){ //original queue is empty, set new to NULL        
        front = nullptr;
        rear = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        front = temp_node = new Node<Queue_entry>(original_node->entry,nullptr);
        while(original_node->next != nullptr)
        {
            original_node = original_node->next;
            //needed to change next and still incriment
            temp_node->next = new Node<Queue_entry>(original_node->entry, nullptr);
            temp_node = temp_node->next;
            //rear->next = temp_node;           
            //rear = temp_node;

        }
        rear = temp_node->next;
    }
}
```